# product_list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'product_id'

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the message in the title for product_id, but I think I've used it correctly on both product_form() and on its path. Can someone help please?

I was gonna name the variable id, but before I could even test it pylint was having trouble with it, so I changed to product_id.

views.py

```
def product_form(request, product_id=0):
    """Formulário de Cadastro de Produtos"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        if product_id==0:
            form = ProductForm()
        else:
            product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
            form = ProductForm(instance=product)
        return render(request, "product_register/product_form.html", {'form': form})
    else:
        form = ProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/product')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('product-form/', views.product_form, name='product_insert'),
    path('product-form/<int:product_id>/', views.product_list, name='product_update'),
    path('category-form/', views.category_form, name='category_insert')
]
```

html

```
{% extends "product_register/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<table class="table table-borderless">
    <thead class="border-bottom font-weight-bold">
        <tr>
            <td> Nome </td>
            <td> Descrição </td>
            <td> Preço </td>
            <td> Categoria </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for product in product_list %}
            <tr>
                <td> {{product.name}} </td>
                <td> {{product.description}} </td>
                <td> {{product.price}} </td>
                <td> 
                {% for category in product.category.all %}
                    {{category.name}}, 
                {% endfor %} 
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <a href="{% url 'product_update' product.id %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                        <i class="far fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
                    </a>    
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: it does seem you are routing to wrong view as error states product_list but you posted product_form

Comment: Thanks, that was it. There in urls when I call the view to the path was views.product_list and should be views.product_form.

Answer (score 1):

you should chnge

```
path('product-form/<int:product_id>/', views.product_list, name='product_update'),
```

to

```
path('product-form/<int:id>/', views.product_list, name='product_update'),
```